# Computing string complexity

Tags: python, string, algorithm, statistics, passwords

My end goal is to compute a single metric which defines the complexity of a given input string.

Here are some examples of what I'd consider **more** complex strings:

```
jkgf82bclov193ng5783jcjus763hesv9w 
389i2vc9wmv02sdcpe34asci3
m32i8s93
```

And here's some examples of what I consider **less** complex strings:

```
ab  
uuuuuuuu
aaaaa11111
a1a1a1a1a1
```

Is anyone aware of any known algorithms/metrics/coefficients that can be used to summarize the complexity of an input string into a single number, normalized between 0 and 1? Perhaps this is a common problem in determining password input complexity?

**My approach**

I'm sure there's a better way than this.

Given a input string `s`, the simple approach I took was to find the maximum amount of information that could be encoded into a string of that length `len(s)`, using the number of unique characters used `len(set(s))`.

i.e. for a string `abb`, length=3, number of unique characters=2. Therefore my complexity metric is 3^2=9. If I define an upper bound then I can normalise the strings between 0 and 1. If the upper bound is 20, 9/20 is the complexity score. If the upper bound is 5, the complexity score is 1.

```
lst = ["000Gg129", "0000aaaa", "a894iunck", "4iu3nclqkerav8e4", "777777777777bbbbbbbbbbb", "36sne8zk"]
upper_bound = 4000000

for s in lst:
    unique_chars = set(s)
    complexity = (len(s) ** len(unique_chars)) / upper_bound
    normalized_complexity = 1 if complexity>1 else complexity
    print(s, normalized_complexity)
```

**Output**

```
1            jkgf82bclov193ng5783jcjus763hesv9w
1            389i2vc9wmv02sdcpe34asci3
0.524288     m32i8s93
2e-06        uuuuuuuu
2.5e-05      aaaaa11111
2.5e-05      a1a1a1a1a1
```

Comment: Obligatory [correct horse battery staple](https://xkcd.com/936/)...

Comment: @Edeki, for your metric, the input `ab` would give an answer 1.0, but `ab` is extremely simple

Comment: @Jon, xkcd is always welcome

Comment: (though I won't be using this metric to validate passwords)

Comment: [This might be interesting to you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Definition)

Comment: Kolmogorov Complexity is useful to develop an intuition for the problem, but seems ill defined for defining the metric in code?

Comment: @Edeki, that's a powerful idea, but another constraint here is speed

Comment: You may be interested in string entropy.  http://blog.dkbza.org/2007/05/scanning-data-for-entropy-anomalies.html

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85724/password-strength-metrics. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength. And finally: unless you have a background in security, leave security to the experts. Don't roll your own. Rather, rely on work done by people who know what they're doing.

Comment: Thanks all for the links, they were helpful

Comment: @Jim, that's sound advice, thankfully my use case has nothing to do with security!